# One to many comparison of data in two different DFs

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes

```
       df1                                       df2

   fname lname  age                      fname   lname  Position
0  Jack  Lee    45                    0  Jack    Ray     25
1  Joy   Kay    34                    1  Chris   Kay     34
2  Jeff  Kim    54                    2  Kim     Xi      34
3  Josh  Chris  29                    3  Josh    McC     24
                                      4  David   Lee     56
                                      5  Aron    Dev     41
                                      6  Jack    Lee     45
                                      7  Shane   Gab     43
                                      8  Joy     Kay     34
                                      9  Jack    Lee     45
```

want to compare fname and lname from two dfs and append to a list, Since there is a possibility of  multiple repetition of entries from df1 in df2.
(Ex. data of row 1 in df1 is present in row 6 and 9 of df2.)

not very clear on how to fetch one row from df1 and compare with all the rows of df2.(One to many Comparison)

please assist me on the same.

Comment: Could you add to your question please on what would be your ideal outcome?

Comment: @sophocles if the conditions match(i.e row1 in df1 == row6 in df2 and row9 in df2):  I want to do some other processing later

Comment: so then I guess the structure in my answer below allows you to do exactly what you want? Or would you prefer something different?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True` will return a clear comparison between the two dataframes based on the columns 'fname' and 'lname':

```
df = pd.merge(df2,
              df1[['fname','lname']],
              on=['fname','lname'],
              how='left',
              indicator=True)
```

prints:

```
print(df)

   fname lname  Position     _merge
0   Jack   Ray        25  left_only
1  Chris   Kay        34  left_only
2    Kim    Xi        34  left_only
3   Josh   McC        24  left_only
4  David   Lee        56  left_only
5   Aron   Dev        41  left_only
6   Jack   Lee        45       both
7  Shane   Gab        43  left_only
8    Joy   Kay        34       both
9   Jack   Lee        45       both
```